# what is noncommutative geometry studying if "noncommutative space" does not exist?

Tags: soft-question, operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

(If this is not a suitable question in here, I will delete it.)

I am new to noncommutative geometry. I know the motivation is to try to generalize the Gelfrand duality to noncommutative $C^{*}$ algebra, so we can study the algrbra of noncommutative functions on some "noncommutative space".

However, it seems that the concept of "noncommutative space" is only taken as an intuition, one can said it does not exist in real sense. Then I am confused, what is the purpose of studying noncommutative geometry? Is this subject only a disguise of studying operator algebra and quantum group, but somehow involving geometrical picture? If that is the case, what is the geometrical part?

Comment: Non-commutative geometry is very useful, whatever space may exist or not. "What is the purpose of studying noncommutative geometry? " - see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88184/what-is-the-significance-of-non-commutative-geometry-in-mathematics), for example. See also [non-commutative algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138366/how-much-algebra-is-there-in-noncommutative-geometry?rq=1).

Comment: One perspective is that "spaces" having observables a commutative algebra of functions describes classical physics. However we know that this is not a useful perspective for quantum mechanics, here observables do not commute for instance. So you would expect the algebra generated by the observables of a quantum system to be non-commutative - its not so stupid to use this metaphor to say that the fundamental structure of physical space is non-commutative in the quantum regime.

Comment: Alain Connes has worked extensively on this. Waving my hands a bit, I think he has lifted many of the operations on functions on a manifold to a non commutative setting like derivations, connections, parallel transport, Laplace operators. Then you can talk about cohomology, index theory and so on. Don't set me an exam on this though!

Comment: People study "non-commutative geometry" because "commutative geometry" fails to describe this reality. At sufficiently small length scale (
Plank scale $~ \sim 1.6 \times 10^{-35}{\rm m}$), quantum effect of gravity is so strong to the point the classical notion of "point" in Euclidean/differential geometry breaks down and no longer a good approximation/description of whatever underneath this space-time continuum.

Comment: @s.harp I can see the point why NCG is relating to physics. Is that the reason why this concept haven't been defined clearly, because no one knows about the fundamental structure of physical spacetime?

Comment: https://people.na.infn.it/~lizzi/chapter6.pdf is a good intro to the notion of noncommutative spaces